# Auto complete search box getting html content instead of text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jquery autocomplete for the search box with php.
i am getting the values through php to autocomplete plugin.

when i start typing and select some result from dropdown or click on some result, the search box is getting the result in html format instead of plain text, like

```
<a href="#/results" class="searchres" onclick="navigate()" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;"><img src=images/pdf-d.png class="icons" /><div class="results" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;">my pro</div><span style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;" class="author">My space in</span></a>
```

i want the text inside `div` `.results` "my pro" when i select the result from the dropdown.  how can i get it?

php:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$sql = "select file_name,img_url,captions from completer";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $fname = $rs['file_name'];
    $iurl = $rs ['img_url'];
    $caption = $rs ['captions'];
    echo '<a href="#/results" class="searchres" onclick="navigate()" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;"><img src='.$iurl.' class="icons" /><div class="results" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;">'."$fname".'</div><span style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;" class="author">'.$caption.'</span></a>'."\n";
}
?>
```

i have also attached the image how it looks like and what it should look like. need help to solve this.

This is how it looks now.

[image]

this is how it should look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    (everything in php)
    then...
    $var_your_var = "<a blah your a tag><img/></a>";
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo $var_your_var ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you should put the html down in your html and echo out the text you want to put within the html tag. Use javascript/ajax to send the input to php and adjust the html accordingly.